# sql - return all rows only if there is no field equal to A?

Tags: sql

I'm a bit stuck. I don't have my current SQL handy, but I'll try to be clear. Say I have a table of student IDs along with a course number and their grade. I want to return students only with no grades equal to A. I don't want just rows that aren't equal to A, but I am trying to find all student IDs with no associated A grades, otherwise students with at least one A will not be returned.

How might I tackle this problem? I'm fairly new to SQL. Thanks

EDIT: Okay, now that I have the actual SQL I can drop my terrible analogy.

```
SELECT  ALL
        ITEMS.QTY_ONHAND AS QTY_ONHAND,
        ITEMS.ITEM_ID AS ITEM_ID_I0,
        MEDORDER.MO_STAT AS MOMO_STAT,
        UPPER(ITEMS.ITEM_ID) AS ITEM_ID_IC,
        ITEMS.RX_DISP AS RX_DISP,
        OMNIS.OMNI_ID AS OMNI_ID,
        MEDORDER.ITEM_ID AS MOITEM_ID
  FROM   ITEMS ITEMS,
         MEDORDER MEDORDER,
         OMNIS OMNIS,
        "PATIENTS" PATIENTS
  WHERE (ITEMS.OMNI_STID = OMNIS.OMNI_STID) AND 
        (PATIENTS.PAT_ID = MEDORDER.PAT_ID) AND 
        (OMNIS.AREA = PATIENTS.AREA) AND (UPPER(ITEMS.ITEM_NAME) LIKE '%Doxycycline%'
     AND MEDORDER.ITEM_ID = UPPER(ITEMS.ITEM_ID)
     AND MEDORDER.MO_STAT='A')
  ORDER BY  ITEMS.QTY_ONHAND DESC, OMNIS.OMNI_ID, MEDORDER.ITEM_ID
```

What I have here is a location, omni_id. My query is looking for every omni_id that has this item_id. This will return multiple results for each omni_id corresponding to multiple medorders for the same item_id. What I want to do, is only return omni_ids that have 0 results for any medorder.mo_stat equal to 'A'. For example, omni_id 3W will have 3 returns, wth medorder_mo_stat equal to A, C, and C. And another, 4S, with medorder.mo_stats of C, C, C. I only want my query to return that 4S group, because it has no medorder.mo_stats of 'A'.

Sorry about the bad explanation.. I'm multitasking a few projects right now and my SQL-fu is not very strong, I'm not sure how to implement the below solutions to get what I'm looking for.

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: "*I am trying to find all student IDs with no associated A grades, otherwise students with at least one A will not be returned*," isn't the same?

Comment: Will be *discarded, sorry

Comment: Do any of the answers help you? If not, provide some more detail.

Comment: I'll be able to try these solutions out in a bit when I sit down with them at work.. Thanks :)

Comment: where is the question content here ?

Answer (score 0):

Based you on your update - I assume this may help, but I'm still not sure I understand your schema, so maybe I am missing something...

```
SELECT
    OMNIS.OMNI_ID AS OMNI_ID,
    COUNT(MEDORDER.ITEM_ID) AS A_COUNT
FROM
    ITEMS
JOIN
    OMNIS
    ON  (ITEMS.OMNI_STID = OMNIS.OMNI_STID)
JOIN
    PATIENTS
    ON  (OMNIS.AREA = PATIENTS.AREA)
LEFT JOIN
    MEDORDER
    ON  (MEDORDER.ITEM_ID = UPPER(ITEMS.ITEM_ID)
    AND (PATIENTS.PAT_ID = MEDORDER.PAT_ID)
    AND (MEORDER.MO_STAT = 'A')
WHERE
    UPPER(ITEMS.ITEM_NAME) LIKE '%Doxycycline%'
GROUP BY
    OMNIS.OMNI_ID
HAVING
    COUNT(MEDORDER.ITEM_ID) = 0
```

---

^EDIT^

---

Lost of ways to solve this one. I would do this:

```
SELECT
    StudentID,
    MAX(CASE Grade WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HasAnA
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    StudentID
HAVING
    MAX(CASE Grade WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Or even just this depending on your table design:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    StudentID
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Grade != 'A'
```

Comment: This excludes results that are A, but still returns other rows for the same ID which I'm trying to exclude, same as below solution

Comment: This first query will only return student ids where the student has no 'A's at all.

Comment: Referencing my update, I don't know if it's a software issue but it's returning the same results for me, aka people with an A, but now it only excludes the particular row instead of the person, and removes duplicated (ie. An A,C,C, now it just returns a C)